# Does $Graff(n,\mathbb{R}^{\infty})$ generate all $n$-dimensional closed Riemannian manifolds $M$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, grassmannian

How does one generate all possible $n$-dimensional simply connected closed Riemannian manifolds $M$ from the affine Grassmannian $Graff(n,V)$? Would $Graff(n,\mathbb{R}^{\infty})$ suffice? (It seems like we need more for it to be closed and simply connected.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by generate in this context?

Comment: As in the affine Grassmannian parametrically exhausts (i.e. it is identically equal to) all possible $n$-dimensional simply connected closed Riemannian manifolds. I think it should be smaller than $Graff(n,\mathbb{R}^{n+1})$ if we just need the conditions of closure and simple-connectedness to be met, however.

Comment: Are you asking about whether every simply connected closed manifold must be homeomorphic to a $Graff(n, \mathbb{R}^{n+1})$ for some $n$? (I'm not sure why you are giving them Riemannian metrics...)

Comment: Yes, this is my question (can they be identified). I suppose the choice of a Riemannian metric is arbitrary (but preferable) @Lorenzo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of simply connected, closed manifolds which are not Grassmannians of $k$ planes in some $\mathbb{R}^n$.

One way to see this is as follows: the dimension of $G(k,n)$ is $k(n - k)$.

Solving for $k(n -k) = 8$, we get $(k,n) \in \{ (1,9), (2,6), (4,6), (8,9) \}$

However, here are five non-homeomorphic $8$-manifolds that are closed and simply connected:

1) $S^2 \times S^2 \times S^2 \times S^2$

2) $S^8$.

3) $S^3 \times S^3 \times S^2$

4) $S^4 \times S^2 \times S^2$

5) $S^6 \times S^2$.

Thus, at least one of these is not homeomorphic to a Grassmannian.

To check that these five products of spheres are not homeomorphic to each other, you can use the Poincare polynomial: https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Poincare_polynomial

Comment: +1 @Lorenzo Thanks! Is there a known expression involving affine Grassmannians that exhausts all simply connected closed manifolds? Going back to my original question, how does one generate all possible $n$-dimensional simply connected closed Riemannian manifolds $M$ from the affine Grassmannian $Graff(n,V)$?

Comment: @Multivariablecalculus I doubt that there's a simple formula... you may want to look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_manifolds

Comment: I should add that spheres (n > 1) are the universal covers of projective spaces , so the manifolds I gave you are products of covers of Grassmannians... (For that matter, I should point out that Grassmannians aren't simply connected in general...)

Comment: Thank you. Hmm, I wonder then if there is any topological object that parameterizes such manifolds that may be explicitly written down?

Comment: I don't think so ... Classifying manifolds is a really hard problem.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1456664/54092

Comment: Thanks, I think I will ask on MO.